# Adding plugins to rails ckeditor gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am using [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/) gem in my Rails application. I am trying to add [LoopIndex Track Changes](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lite) plugin to my CKEditor.

I downloaded the plugins with all dependencies and extracted them in `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/` post which I added the `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` to include:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'lite';
}
```

I have tried looking at the solution on the [github repo](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/450) and [other links](http://krazedkrish.com/blog/2016/11/20/how-to-add-plugins-to-ckeditor-in-rails/) but cannot get it to work. Has anyone successfully managed to add a plugin to the gem.

Comment: What is `post` in `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/ post` ?

Comment: Have you gone through this - http://www.loopindex.com/lite/doc/

Comment: @arjun corrected the formatting issue. I meant to say after extracting I made (post) changes to the config.js file. I have gone through the link you suggested but except for point 2 there all other steps are purely optional for advanced use. I even tried adding other plugins similar to the one referred in the github repo above (youtube) but that did not work as well.

Comment: Well without a log file, I can't say much. You need to raise this issue with the developers there.